# Is it possible to convert this SQL query to linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to count three values on a single table. In plain SQL, it is written like this way:

```
select 
    count (*) as num_products,
    sum(case when CreatedAt > '{sql.ToSqlDate(_CreatedAfter)}' then 1 else 0 end) num_new,
    sum(case when UpdatedAt > '{sql.ToSqlDate(_UpdatedAfter)}' then 1 else 0 end)  num_updated 
from 
    Products
```

While switching to EF Core, I tried to convert it to Linq, like this

```
var res = (from p in _db.Products
           let total = _db.Products.Count()
           let NewProducts = _db.Products.Count(s => s.CreatedAt > crDate.Date)
           let UpdatedProducts = _db.Products.Count(s => s.UpdatedAt > updDate.Date) 
           select new { total, NewProducts, UpdatedProducts } );
var response = res.ToList();
```

but the resulting SQL query seems not optimized

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Products] AS [p0]) AS [total], 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Products] AS [s] 
     WHERE [s].[CreatedAt] > '2019-07-31') AS [NewProducts], 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Products] AS [s0] 
     WHERE [s0].[UpdatedAt] > '2019-07-01') AS [UpdatedProducts] 
FROM 
    [Products] AS [p]
```

Maybe somebody can help to translate the original SQL query to linq?

tia
ish

Comment: why are you `let` from `_db.Products.` instead of `p`?

Comment: i am not experienced with linq to sql. you think it is possible here to let from p and it will optimize the query? if yes, i'll check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more literal translation of that query, that generates a query more likely to execute in a single scan of the target table would be:

```
var q =
    from p in db.Products
    select new
    {
        p.Id,
        NewProduct = p.CreatedAt > DateTime.Parse("2019-07-31") ? 1 : 0,
        UpdatedProduct = p.UpdatedAt > DateTime.Parse("2019-07-01") ? 1 : 0
    } into counts
    group counts by 1 into grouped
    select new
    {
        ProductCount = grouped.Count(),
        NewProductCount = grouped.Sum(r => r.NewProduct),
        UpdatedProductCount = grouped.Sum(r => r.UpdatedProduct)
    };
```

Which translates to something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [ProductCount], 
       SUM([t].[NewProduct]) AS [NewProductCount], 
       SUM([t].[UpdatedProduct]) AS [UpdatedProductCount]
FROM (
    SELECT [p].[Id], CASE
        WHEN [p].[CreatedAt] > @__Parse_0
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS [NewProduct], CASE
        WHEN [p].[UpdatedAt] > @__Parse_1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS [UpdatedProduct], 1 AS [Key]
    FROM [Products] AS [p]
) AS [t]
GROUP BY [t].[Key]
```

Comment: thank you again.. seems its time to retire my old sql helper lib :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `from` clause in your linq because you aren't not going over the rows. just use three statements:

```
var total = _db.Products.Count();
var NewProducts = _db.Products.Count(s => s.CreatedAt > crDate.Date);
var UpdatedProducts = _db.Products.Count(s => s.UpdatedAt > updDate.Date) ;
```

Comment: But this goes 3 times thru the data.

Comment: yes, but if it is not a lot of data, this answer this much simpler then David's answer

Comment: no, if i can't find correct linq statement i'll just use sqlrecordset ;)